# How to configure SQL Server Managment Studio to show all text data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I configure SQL Server Managment Studio to show all text data from a field?

Comment: Query -> Results To -> Results To Text

Comment: Is this was you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11897950/512365

Answer (score 1):

you can also use rightClick/ResultsTo/Results to Text. this will give you all of the info, but it will have a *lot* of white space

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer, the grid results does limit it. Just click with right button and export it to .csv file, and it will be all data from the field.